# Implementation of an UniqueIdentifier class

Tags: java

I have a requirement to implement a generic UniqueIdentifier which can cover identifiers like OrderId, TrackingID, scannableId and other Ids. The ids, as they are now, are either `Long` or `String`.
Below is my implementation of the UniqueIdentifier class --

```
public class UniqueIdentifier {
    String stringValue;
    Long longValue;
    boolean isLong;
    boolean isString;

    public UniqueIdentifier(String value) {
        setStringValue(value);
        try 
        {
            setLongValue(Long.parseLong(value));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nex) 
        {
            setLong(false);
        }
    }
    public UniqueIdentifier(Long value) {
        setLongValue(value);
        setStringValue(Long.toString(value));
    }
    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }
    private void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }
    public Long getLongValue() {
        return longValue;
    }
    private void setLongValue(Long longValue) {
        this.longValue = longValue;
    }
    public boolean isLong() {
        return isLong;
    }
    private void setLong(boolean isLong) {
        this.isLong = isLong;
    }
    public boolean isString() {
        return isString;
    }
    private void setString(boolean isString) {
        this.isString = isString;
    }       
}
```

Is there anything that i can do better here

Comment: Are you using an ORM, hibernate/JPA or anyhing else?

Give examples of how you would use this class. As it is, it's not very usable.

Most important of all, where and how did this requirement for a generic unique identifier came?

Answer (score 4):

I think this one screams for usage of generics.

ie.

```
public class UniqueIdentifier<T> {
    T theValue;
    public UniqueIdentifier( T t ) {
        theValue = t;
    }
    public T getValue() {
        return theValue;
    }
}
```

Can even be extened with a nice factory method.

Comment: Of course they might actually be needing just an `Entity<T>` where `T` is the type of the id, either `Long` or `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Although your requirements are not clear, namely, why unwrapped `Long` and `String` objects are not enough or if an identifier can be both simultaneously, I'd say that this would be better served by the following:

```
public abstract class UniqueIdentifier { /* no data */ }

public class LongIdentifier extends UniqueIdentifier { ... }
public class StringIdentifier extends UniqueIdentifier { ... }
```

In addition:

- make sure you define `equals` and `hashCode`, and maybe, implement `Comparable`, as identifiers tend to be used as map keys
- omit setters, making your identifiers immutable, again, for using them as map keys

You can check for the class of each object with `instanceof`, but you should worry if you need to use it a lot. Would such functionality be better server by additional methods in the base class?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `isLong` and `isString` fields, because they will **always** be false! They're initialised to false on construction of a `UniqueIdentifier` and you never set them to true.

This points to a deeper problem: the `isLong` and `longValue` have more to do with each other than your code makes clear (similarly for `isString` and `stringValue`). I think your intent is that `longValue` either contains a number (in which case `isLong` should be true), or `longValue` is `null` and `isLong` is `false`. If that's the case, you should get rid of the `isLong` field and setter, and replace the getter by

```
public boolean getLong() {
    return longValue == null;
}
```

There's a problem if you want to be able to use `UniqueIdentifier((Long) null)` as something that contains an 'absent' `Long` value, but I think you should rethink your design if you need that.

You could also look into using [the `Optional<T>` type from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) or one of it's (many) variants.

Comment: I can not follow this: "will always be false". If he calls `setString(true)`, then it is true, not false. - I think you mistyped the method name in your code example, it should be `isLong()`?

Comment: `setString(boolean)` is a private method, and is never called from the code, so `isString` can't change from its initial value of `false`.